# Why does multiple WHERE conditions in a PDO prepared SELECT statement cause the query to break

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When this query is executed I get the response (through AJAX) I expect. It works.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT item_location AS Location,  users_description AS Description, price AS Price  FROM sale_items WHERE item_type IN ($cs_vals)”);
```

But when I add another table column name to the WHERE clause like so:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT item_location AS Location,  users_description AS Description, price AS Price  FROM sale_items WHERE (item_type, map_region) IN ($cs_vals)”);
```

....I get a 'JSON.parse: unexpected character....' message in the console and nothing displayed in my webpage. Why is this? What am I doing wrong here. Thanks in advance for any help.
BTW, $cs_vals is a list of comma separated values in the format ('a', 'b', 'c'...). This comma separated list has been generated by

```
$cs_vals = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) '?';
```

The $arr variable is an array of non NULL values extracted from a user generated form.

Comment: shouldnt your $cs_vals be something like `((a,b), (c,d), (d,e))`

Comment: I don't know how the first query is working, because the SQL syntax is not valid. You can't have a `WHERE` clause if you have no `FROM` clause. I would guess you are not showing the code that you say works.

Comment: Please review [ask], including [mcve].   Further, your SQL looks open to SQL injection attacks - you should look at [binding parameters](https://webapplog.com/how-to-use-pdo-and-parameter-binding/) instead.

Comment: Mixing PDO with string interpolation? Not cool.

Comment: To @Juan Carlos Oropeza do you mean that the correct formmat for $cs_vals is ((a,b), (c,d), (d,e)) ?

Comment: My apologies to @Bill Karwin My code does include a FROM clause but I accidently ommited it from my original question. I have edited the question so that it is now correct. Thanks for taking the trouble to reply.

Comment: To I am basing my query on an example from [link](phpdelusions.net/pdo#in]) This is the example: 
    $arr = [1,2,3]; $in = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?'; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($in)"; $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stm->execute($arr); $data = $stm->fetchAll();

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you know about the FROM

You have to check one at a time:

```
WHERE ((item_type) IN ($cs_vals) 
OR (map_region) IN ($cs_vals))
```

Unless you are trying to find the combo in an array.

Comment: If OP is searching for ordered pairs then this query will produce incorrect results.

Comment: I agree. Hence my last sentence. Based on the first query, I did not think this was the case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but I keep getting the parse error.

Answer (score 0):

You use `EXISTS` and instead of `$cs_vals` you create an inline table using `UNION` so you can validate if the tuple match your list.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72a495b/7)**

```
SELECT item_location AS Location,  users_description AS Description, price AS Price  
FROM sale_items 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM (SELECT 'A' as item_type, 1 as map_region
                    UNION 
                    SELECT 'B' as item_type, 2 as map_region
                    ) as T
              WHERE sale_items.item_type = T.item_type
                AND sale_items.map_region = T.map_region
              )
```

Also you can use IN but need compare with tuples like this:

```
SELECT item_location AS Location,  users_description AS Description, price AS Price  
FROM sale_items 
WHERE  (item_type, map_region) IN (('A',1),('B',2));
```